# Nemo File Manager on Ubuntu 12.10 (Unity)?

Tags: unity, 12.10, filemanager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to completely integrate Nemo with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190529/how-to-completely-integrate-nemo-with-ubuntu)

Linux Mint uses Nemo File Manager (fork of Nautilus) and how can I use it on Ubuntu 12.10 (Unity desktop)? Is there any problem after install?