# How do I install Nemo file manager?

Tags: installation, nemo

How do I install Nemo File Manager, a fork of nautilus 3.4 by the Linux Mint team?

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04, see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/517515/installing-nemo-file-manager-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Instructions since they added it to the repositories in 13.04+!

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

---

## Use the ones below if you want a slightly-more-up-to-date version.

### DO NOT USE THESE IN 13.10, unless you aren't using a unity-based Ubuntu flavour.

## To install the stable version of Nemo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

### To install the bleeding edge version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

Note: Nemo also shows up as Files in the dash, so the first instance of Files should hopefully be Nemo.

---

### If you want to continue using Nautilus for drawing your desktop icons:

Show all the startup apps:

```
sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/nemo-autostart.desktop
```

Then, uncheck the item under Startup Applications that says:

**Files**
Start Nemo desktop at login

Comment: How can i do this without installing Cinnamon?

Comment: @dhojgaard You never needed to install Cinnamon. It just adds it to the repo. Also, now you can use `sudo apt-get install nemo` in >= 13.04. They finally added it to the repositories.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser with the 2nd and 3rd methods in your answer, Cinnamon will automatically be installed alongside nemo. `Instructions since they added it to the repositories!` should probably read `Instructions for Ubuntu 13.04 and above!`, I went straight ahead and added the ppas in 13.10, this lead to Cinnamon being installed, I couldn't log into unity anymore since [Cinnamon breaks](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1188947) [unity in 13.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/361392/does-cinnamon-2-0-really-break-your-13-10-desktop).

Comment: @vikki indeed! Seems that they strangely labelled it as depending on cinnamon. How annoying.

Comment: Looked into it, seems you can apt-get download the package, then force install it with dpkg -i --force-all. There's no direct way to ignore a dependency with apt-get.

Comment: What is the problem with using in 13.10? I haven't tried, I just want to know what I might get myself into.

Comment: @plattnum cinnamon breaking unity in 13.10. Further up in the comments. I have posted the way to avoid this issue. Simply `apt-get download nemo`, then `sudo dpkg -i --force-all nemo.deb` or whatever the name of the .deb file it got is.

Comment: Is it a good idea to add Cinnamon `PPA` to say `ElementaryOS`? I've seen weird things happening when I added `PopOS` PPA to an Ubuntu Desktop...

Answer (score 4):

### Nemo without Cinamon

version 1.8.4

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/mint    
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

Extra plugins

```
sudo apt-get install nemo-compare nemo-dropbox nemo-fileroller nemo-pastebin nemo-seahorse nemo-share nemo-preview nemo-rabbitvcs
```

source **Noobslab**: http://www.noobslab.com/2013/10/nemo-file-manager-with-extensions-for.html

To install the version (latest) 2.0.3 check this new post in webupd8: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Install **Nemo** for Ubuntu with Unity.

Note: Do not use this PPA if you're using Cinnamon in Ubuntu.

*The PPA provides Nemo* **2.8** for Ubuntu *15.10, 15.04 and 14.04*.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
```

To launch Nemo, search for `Nemo` in the Dash.

**Optional extensions** :

```
sudo apt-get install nemo-compare nemo-dropbox nemo-media-columns nemo-pastebin nemo-seahorse nemo-share nemo-emblems nemo-image-converter nemo-audio-tab
```

To install the RabbitVCS extension (requires [RabbitVCS PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rabbitvcs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)) execute :

```
sudo apt-get install nemo-rabbitvcs
```

<sub>reference [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Install **Nemo** for Ubuntu and **Nautilus** patches:

For **Unity** it can be installed like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daschuer/nemo-merge
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nemo
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

For **Cinnamon** it can be installed like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daschuer/nemo-nautilus-merge-cinnamon
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nemo
```

It includes the Gnome patches from the Web Upd8 version a lot of Nautilus fixes and Improvements (2819 commits ahead). Most notable is the improved search behavior.

A complete list can be found here: 
https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/pull/1041

The source code can be found here: 
https://github.com/daschuer/nemo/tree/nemo_314_merge_nemo_base