# Installing Nemo file manager on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, 32-bit, filemanager, nemo

How to install Nemo file manager on **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 Bit**

Please anyone help me.
Which repositories should I use for installing Nemo On Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a very good port of Nemo from Cinnamon to Ubuntu on [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html).  The basics of installation are

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

This will install Nemo, and set the system to use Nemo for the desktop and as the default file manager.

The webupd8 site also has several extensions available for Nemo.

Comment: Works great on Ubuntu 14.04.1 x86_64