# Ubuntu 20: Files 'search'

Tags: nautilus, files

The file manager in Ubuntu 20. I can search for files according to size, but why if I search for files, can I then not filter or sort them according to size, (windows file manager for example, I can click on the size column and the files are sorted by size), or search the 'searched files' according to size?

Comment: Please clarify your release. Desktop and server releases use a *yy.mm* format for releases, *yy* being used only by snap based specialist releases (usually installed on appliances/devices which are headless without screen/keyboard).  There is no Ubuntu 20, closest is Ubuntu Core 20, which is a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS you may mean.

Comment: True: the search and filter functions of Nautilus are rudimentary. As to *why*: nobody has programmed it, yet, I suppose.

Comment: Related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/294421/how-do-i-install-nemo-file-manager

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible,
Gnome Devs don't think, that (imho) essential features are important for a file manager.

Comment from a developer to this issue:

> The use cases are not clear

See these bug reports:

- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/374
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/888
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1698351 (Importance = low).

In a comment on the first link above, a developer said now almost 2 years ago:

> The issue is marked as *Stretch* and that means it is something we want in the long term.

You might try a different file manager, e.g. [Nemo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294421/how-do-i-install-nemo-file-manager) that forked from Nautilus a while ago.