# Customize nemo keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, nautilus, keyboard, shortcut-keys, nemo

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 and ran through the steps outlined on [Completely integrate nemo in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/279497/183873).

I understand that Nemo is a cloned-fork off of Nautilus and was hoping that I'd be able to adjust the keyboard shortcuts for it in the same way... For Nautilus  we can edit the "accels" file at `~/.config/nautilus/accels`.

Does Nemo not have this ability?

The version of Nemo on my system is 1.8.2.

Answer (score 7):

[Anand Sharma](https://askubuntu.com/users/183873/anand-sharma) answer (after I [edited](https://askubuntu.com/posts/333088/revisions) his question):

> The "accels" file for Nemo when installed with the method linked to
>   above is located at: `~/.gnome2/accels/nemo`. The two
>   files, `~/.config/nautilus/accels` and `~/.gnome2/accels/nemo` are very close to
>   the same.
>
> The reason why I desperately wanted to find how to edit
>   keyboard-shortcuts was cause I HATE the default for focusing on the
>   location-bar which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. Practically
>   *every other application* you can think of (e.g. Windows Explorer, Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox... list goes on) that has an
>   "address bar" places focus there using the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
>   combination.
>
> Editing the following line in either of the "accel" files did the
>   trick for me (make sure you remove the semi-colon, too):
>
> From:
>
> ```
> ; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Edit Location" "<Primary>L")
> ```
>
> To:
>
> ```
> (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Edit Location" "<Alt>d")
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I also had to define the `GNOME22_USER_DIR` environment variable. All in all, this is what I did:

1. Add `export GNOME22_USER_DIR="$HOME/.config/nemo"` to `~/.profile`.
2. Create an empty file `~/.config/nemo/accels/nemo`.
3. Restart the System, start Nemo, close Nemo.
4. The file created in 2. now should have been filled with all available actions. If not, see below list.
5. Edit the desired lines, remove the comment character (`;`) and spaces from the start. **Save your changes in a backup. Nemo sometimes seems to overwrite that file partially.**
6. Restart the system.

For reference, this is what Nemo currently writes into that file on my system (As you see, it also lists user scripts):

```
; nemo GtkAccelMap rc-file         -*- scheme -*-
; this file is an automated accelerator map dump
;
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/New Window" "<Primary>n")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Sidebar List" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/File" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Sort by Size" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenAlternate" "<Primary><Shift>o")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/RenameSelectAll" "<Shift>F2")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Show Hide Menubar" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Zoom In" "<Primary>plus")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Cut" "<Primary>x")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Go to Computer" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Create Link" "<Primary>m")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Redo" "<Primary>y")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/CompactView" "<Primary>3")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Add Bookmark" "<Primary>d")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Preferences" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ClipboardActions/Copy" "<Primary>c")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ScriptsGroup/script_file:\\s\\s\\shome\\snils\\s.local\\sshare\\snemo\\sscripts\\smake_folder_starter.py" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Reversed Order" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/TabsPrevious" "<Primary>Page_Up")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenAccel" "<Alt>Down")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Delete" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/No Templates" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationDelete" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Stop" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/New Documents" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationCopy" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Go" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Close" "<Primary>w")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Connect To Server Link" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Location Eject Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Stop Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationRestoreFromTrash" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab9" "<Alt>0")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Location Unmount Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenAsRoot" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Sort by Name" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Keep Aligned" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Poll" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Edit" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Zoom Out" "<Primary>minus")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab8" "<Alt>9")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Go to Network" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Show Thumbnails" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenInNewTab" "<Primary><Shift>t")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OtherApplication2" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Move to next pane" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/NemoShortcuts" "<Primary>F1")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Back" "<Alt>Left")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Bookmarks" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Select Pattern" "<Primary>s")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Open With" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab7" "<Alt>8")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/BrowseMoveTo" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OtherApplication1" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/TabsMoveLeft" "<Primary><Shift>Page_Up")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Location Start Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab6" "<Alt>7")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Properties" "<Alt>Return")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Home" "<Alt>Home")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Go to Trash" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Location Poll" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Location Stop Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Show Hide Sidebar" "F9")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Mount Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Copy to Home" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab5" "<Alt>6")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Move to Desktop" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Reset to Defaults" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationOpenInNewTab" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Sort by Detailed Type" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab4" "<Alt>5")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenInTerminal" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/CopyToMenu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Forward" "<Alt>Right")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab3" "<Alt>4")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/About Nemo" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Clean Up" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Open" "<Primary>o")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/TabsMoveRight" "<Primary><Shift>Page_Down")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/IconView" "<Primary>1")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/View" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Sort by Modification Date" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Select All" "<Primary>a")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab2" "<Alt>3")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationTrash" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Unmount Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationPasteFilesInto" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab0" "<Alt>1")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Eject Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenContainingFolder" "<Primary><Alt>o")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab1" "<Alt>2")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Pin File" "<Primary><Shift>d")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Duplicate" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Edit Location" "<Primary>l")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationProperties" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Help" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Close All Windows" "<Primary>q")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Show Hide Toolbar" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Copy to Desktop" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Self Eject Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Rename" "F2")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/SplitViewNextPane" "F6")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Unfavorite File" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Empty Trash" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Show Hide Statusbar" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Connect to Server" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Go to Templates" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/New Tab" "<Primary>t")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/NemoHelp" "F1")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/FollowSymbolicLink" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/ZoomOutAccel" "<Primary>KP_Subtract")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/ZoomInAccel2" "<Primary>KP_Add")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Manual Layout" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Edit Bookmarks" "<Primary>b")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/New Empty Document" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/NemoPluginManager" "<Alt>p")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Start Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Unpin File" "<Primary><Shift>d")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Self Start Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Undo" "<Primary>z")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/TabsNext" "<Primary>Page_Down")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Arrange Items" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Sort by Trash Time" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ClipboardActions/Select All" "<Primary>a")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Self Poll" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/New Folder" "<Primary><Shift>n")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Location Mount Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Reload" "<Primary>r")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Restore From Trash" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/MoveToMenu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Favorite File" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Up" "<Alt>Up")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenCloseParent" "<Shift><Alt>Down")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Paste Files Into" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Copy to next pane" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Zoom Normal" "<Primary>0")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Search" "<Primary>f")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Self Unmount Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Move to Home" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Self Mount Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/PropertiesAccel" "<Primary>i")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Self Stop Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Paste" "<Primary>v")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ClipboardActions/Paste" "<Primary>v")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationOpenAlternate" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/ListView" "<Primary>2")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/BrowseCopyTo" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Sidebar Places" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Show Hidden Files" "<Primary>h")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationCut" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ClipboardActions/Cut" "<Primary>x")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/SplitViewSameLocation" "<Alt>s")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Copy" "<Primary>c")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Sidebar Tree" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Trash" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/ZoomInAccel" "<Primary>equal")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Sort by Type" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Invert Selection" "<Primary><Shift>i")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Show Hide Extra Pane" "F3")
```

References: [1](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1696073#p1696073), [2](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2057171#p2057171), [3](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/72f2fa785efc8fd432eb2bd843b75287ae1adc1c/libnemo-private/nemo-file-utilities.c#L166-L187=), [4](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/1771)

Comment: The file `~/.config/nemo/accels/nemo` already exists by default on Linux Mint 20.04