# Lock screen elements & Wallpaper frozen

Tags: unity, desktop-environments, filemanager, desktop-background

I have finally made the switch from Windows to Ubuntu and now have a problem:

The elements shown in the lockscreen on boot (Ubuntu logo in the middle and watermark in bottom left corner) stay there even when I'm entering desktop and I cannot change the wallpaper anymore.

How can I remove them again? They weren't there at first, but after updating Ubuntu with Update Center, the problem occurred.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I installed Nemo and since then it was handling the desktop. I disabled it at some point, leaving no other application to handle it because standard file manager was already uninstalled. I made Nemo again the desktop handler.

For a way to enable *nemo* to handle the desktop like normally *nautilus* does, check this answer

- [How to completely integrate Nemo with Ubuntu? (Konstigt's answer)](https://askubuntu.com/a/279497/117103) .

Comment: You finally enabled nautilus to handle the desktop?